# Output behaves abruptly while executing implementing IPC pipes in C and Linux

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc

The complete code is

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 

int main()
{
int pc[2]; // parent writes to child, child reads from parent
int cp[2]; // parent reads from child, childs writes to parent
pid_t ck_pid; // checking fork pid

if (pipe(pc)==-1) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed - pc \n" ); 
    return 1; 
}
if (pipe(cp)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed - cp \n" ); 
    return 1;
}

ck_pid=fork();
if (ck_pid<0)
{
    perror("Failure : Child Process Creation \n");
    return 1;
}
else if (ck_pid==0)
{
    // code for child
    //int lc1=0;
    char rb[100];
    char wb[100];
    int str_cpr_r;
    int str_cpr_r_1;
    char t_buff_1[100];
    char t_buff_2[100];
    int seq_cnt_1=0;

    //for (lc1=0;lc1<5;lc1++)
    //{
    while(true)
    {
        pid_t c_tid;
        c_tid=getpid();
        printf("Child (%d) with count : %d \n", c_tid, seq_cnt_1);
        // 0 is the reading end, 1 is the writing end
        // pc is child reads from parent
        //close(pc[1]); // closing writing end before reading pc
        read(pc[0], rb, sizeof(rb));
        //close(pc[0]); // closing after reading pc
        printf("Content from Parent is : %s \n", rb);
        //sprintf(t_buff_1, "get-started-%d", seq_cnt_1);
        strcpy(t_buff_1, "get-started");
        str_cpr_r=strcmp(rb, t_buff_1);
        strcpy(t_buff_2, "get-out");
        str_cpr_r_1=strcmp(rb, t_buff_1);
        if (str_cpr_r==0)
        { 
            printf("Read in child successful \n");
            //strcpy(wb, "OK");
            sprintf(wb, "%d", (seq_cnt_1*5));
            // cp is childs writes to parent
            //close(cp[0]); // closing reading end before writing cp
            write(cp[1], wb, strlen(wb)+1);
            //close(cp[1]); // closing after writing cp
        }
        if (str_cpr_r_1==0)
        {
            close(cp[0]);
            close(cp[1]);
            close(pc[0]);
            close(pc[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    //exit(0);
    seq_cnt_1++;
}
else if (ck_pid>0)
{
    // code for parent
    //int lc2;
    //for (lc2=0;lc2<5;lc2++)
    //{
    //pipe(pc);
    //pipe(cp);  
    bool winner_avl=false;
    int seq_cnt=0;  
    char wb[100];
    char rb[100];
    pid_t p_tid;
    int final_value=0;
    while (winner_avl==false)
    {
        printf("Turn ID : %d \n", seq_cnt);
        p_tid=getpid();
        printf("Parent (%d) with count : %d \n", p_tid, seq_cnt);
        // 0 is the reading end, 1 is the writing end
        strcpy(wb, "get-started");
        //sprintf(wb, "get-started-%d", seq_cnt);
        // pc is parent writes to child
        //close(pc[0]); // closing reading end before writing pc
        write(pc[1], wb, strlen(wb)+1);
        //close(pc[1]); // closing after writing pc
        sleep(10);
        // cp is parent reads from child
        //close(cp[1]); // closing writing end before reading cp
        read(cp[0], rb, sizeof(rb));
        //close(cp[0]); // closing after reading cp
        printf("Content from Child is : %s \n", rb);
        final_value=final_value+atoi(rb);
        printf("Final value is now : %d \n\n\n", final_value);
        //int str_cpr_r;
        /*str_cpr_r=strcmp(rb, "OK");
        if (str_cpr_r==0)
        {
            printf("Read in parent successful \n");
        }
        */
        seq_cnt++;
        if (final_value>=10||seq_cnt>=5)
        {
            winner_avl=true;
        }
        //wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("Time to finish things, Final : %d \n", final_value);
    strcpy(wb, "get-out");
    close(pc[0]);
    write(pc[1], wb, strlen(wb)+1);
    wait(NULL);
    close(cp[0]);
    close(cp[1]);
    close(pc[0]);
    close(pc[1]);
}
else
{
    printf("Problem in forking");
}    
return 0;
}
```

**The problem is after the first iteration the screen freezes**

> Turn ID : 0
>
> Parent (17254) with count : 0
>
> Child (17255) with count : 0
>
> Content from Parent is : get-started
>
> Read in child successful
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Turn ID : 1  Parent (17254) with count : 1

**If I follow the closing unused pipe ends normally I don't get any data**

> Turn ID : 0
>
> Parent (17495) with count : 0
>
> Child (17496) with count : 0
>
> Content from Parent is : get-started
>
> Read in child successful
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Turn ID : 1
>
> Parent (17495) with count : 1
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Turn ID : 2
>
> Parent (17495) with count : 2
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Turn ID : 3
>
> Parent (17495) with count : 3
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Turn ID : 4
>
> Parent (17495) with count : 4
>
> Content from Child is : 0
>
> Final value is now : 0
>
> Time to finish things, Final : 0

**Please help.**

Comment: Close the file descriptors once (you’re trying to close some twice) before you do the waiting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan.
I took [close(pc[1]); // closing writing end before reading pc], [close(cp[0]); // closing reading end before writing cp] out of while loop in child, and 
[close(pc[0]); // closing reading end before writing pc], [close(cp[1]); // closing writing end before reading cp] out of while loop in parent.
This did the trick.